# In a standalone SVG file, is it possible to position one object relative to another using only CSS?

Tags: css, svg, tooltip, positioning, justify

[Here is a demo SVG file](http://images.wikia.com/digitalrupture/images/b/b2/000._post_demo_large_CSS_only_tooltips.svg). Please use Firefox for viewing because currently it seems to be the only properly showing browser.

The task is to construct a pure SVG document (e.g. not html-embedded) that will be able to show tooltips using only CSS features (no JS and also no `:before`/`:after` pseudo-elements). I managed to achieve this by using the `HTML` `foreignObject` element.

However, I can not find if it is possible to position such elements in relation (e.g. 10px to the left and top from it) to other in-document SVG objects without using JavaScript for it and without embedding the SVG file itself into some other document format (e.g. HTML).

In the final version of the file there will be 20-30+ tooltips, so it is desirable to avoid manual positioning. I was hoping there would be something for "attaching" them to other objects (withthe use of their IDs) or at least to their parent objects, but my search results only return documentation and questions regarding JS or HTML implementations.

add. notes:

1) CSS-only SVG file is required because the file is intended to be  used on wiki sites, which prohibid SVGs that have javascript in them.

2) If I understand correctly, displaying HTML formatting in `HTML` `foreignObject` element is not a current SVG standard requirement for SVG user agents (i.a. web-browsers). However, Firefox seems to properly display them, and I’d rather use that (even not fully supported) opportunity. If I am missing some easier ways of achieving the same thing — please do tell about them.

3) SVG code backup: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/BwasnMuL).

Comment: In SVG, positions are attributes not styles, so I'm pretty sure you can't achieve what you want using just CSS.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to be sure. Can you repost your reply in a form of answer so I can mark the question answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't achieve this effect using just CSS because positions in SVG are attributes, not styles.